# Как преобразовать массив в словарь на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть массив данных такого вида:

```
['BMW 1-Series (F20), b38b15 b47d20 b58b30o0 n13b16 n20b20b n55b30 n47d20',
 'BMW 1-Series (F21), n13b16 n47d20 n55b30',
 'BMW 1-Series (E82), n43b20 n47d20 n52b30 n55b30m0 n54b30to n54b30']
```

Как можно его преобразовать в словарь с несколькими значениями для одного ключа:

```
{'BMW 1-Series (F20)': ['b47d20', 'b58b30o0', 'n13b16', 'n20b20b', 'n55b30', 'n47d20'],
 'BMW 1-Series (F21)': ['n13b16', 'n47d20', 'n55b30'],
 'BMW 1-Series (E82)': ['n43b20', 'n47d20', 'n52b30', 'n55b30m0', 'n54b30to', 'n54b30']}
```

Заранее спасибо за советы!

Дополню что делал, чтобы получить эти данные:
С помощью BeautifulSoup получаю данные, которые мне нужны. Спарсились они очень криво, поэтому я их попытался привести к более менее читаемому виду.

```
all_links = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'engines-list-page__section_generation col-md-3')

s_e = []

for item in all_links:
    item_title = item.text
    s_e.append(item_title.replace('\n', ' ').strip().replace('       ', ', ').replace('   ', ' ').replace('      ', ' ').replace('\',', ',\n').replace(', , , , , , , , , , ,  ', ', '))
    
print(s_e)
```

Я могу их продолжить дальше с помощью replace доводить до нужного вида и преобразовать их в словарь, но мне кажется, это неверно и есть более простые способы.

Comment: В чистом питоне **НЕТ МАССИВОВ** ))  Но есть списки. Вы сами что пытались делать? Это не сложная задача, но её нужно хотя бы попытаться решать

Comment: Создаете словарь. Перебираете спискок, каждый элемент делить split'ом по `', '` получив левую часть с ключом и правую с строкой идентификаторов, которую снова делить split'ом (можно не передавать ничего, т.к. функция принимает пробел по умолчанию). При переборе списка заполняете словарь по ключу

Comment: @CrazyElf я пытаюсь уже два дня. Дополнил как я получил данные. Просто знаний не хватает пока что))

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо большое, попробую.

Comment: "Спарсились они очень криво" а ссылку не скинете, что парсили?

Comment: @СергейШашко Криво спарсились, скорее всего из-за моих рук)) https://bmwband.ru/engines

Comment: @Stepan52 , Ну да, было бы проще парсить не в одну строку, а каждый элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ладно, раз дают готовый код, вот в одну строку для разнообразия:

```py
lst = \
['BMW 1-Series (F20), b38b15 b47d20 b58b30o0 n13b16 n20b20b n55b30 n47d20',
 'BMW 1-Series (F21), n13b16 n47d20 n55b30',
 'BMW 1-Series (E82), n43b20 n47d20 n52b30 n55b30m0 n54b30to n54b30']

d = {k: v.split() for k,v in map(lambda x: x.split(','), lst)}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Начальные данные
source = ['BMW 1-Series (F20), b38b15 b47d20 b58b30o0 n13b16 n20b20b n55b30 n47d20',
 'BMW 1-Series (F21), n13b16 n47d20 n55b30',
 'BMW 1-Series (E82), n43b20 n47d20 n52b30 n55b30m0 n54b30to n54b30']
# Создаём пустой dict
d = dict()
 
# Пробегаемся по каждой строке
for line in source:
  # разделяем строку на ключ и значение
  # где значение в виде строки элементов разделённых пробелами
  key, values = line.split(',')
  # разделяем строку со значениями на список строк
  values = list(map(lambda value: value.strip(), values.split()))
  # добавляем с словарь нашу пару ключ-значение
  d[key.strip()] = values

print(d)
```

Результат следующий:

```
{'BMW 1-Series (F20)': ['b38b15', 'b47d20', 'b58b30o0', 'n13b16', 'n20b20b', 'n55b30', 'n47d20'], 
'BMW 1-Series (F21)': ['n13b16', 'n47d20', 'n55b30'], 
'BMW 1-Series (E82)': ['n43b20', 'n47d20', 'n52b30', 'n55b30m0', 'n54b30to', 'n54b30']}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю вариант вместе с парсером:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup, Tag

response = requests.get('https://bmwband.ru/engines')

soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

def parse_section(section: Tag):
    header = ht.get_text(strip=True) if (
        ht := section.find(
            'div', 
            class_='engines-list-page__section_generation_title'
        )
    ) else None
    return header, [a.get_text(strip=True) for a in section.find_all('a')]

pprint(
    dict(
        map(
            parse_section, 
            soup.find_all(
                'div', 
                class_='engines-list-page__section_generation'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

`output`

```latex
{'BMW 1-Series (E81)': ['n45b16', 'n46b20', 'n47d20', 'n52b30'],
 'BMW 1-Series (E82)': ['n43b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n52b30',
                        'n55b30m0',
                        'n54b30to',
                        'n54b30'],
 'BMW 1-Series (E87)': ['n43b16',
                        'n43b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n52b30',
                        'n45b16',
                        'n46b20'],
 'BMW 1-Series (E88)': ['n43b20', 'n47d20', 'n52b30', 'n55b30m0', 'n54b30'],
 'BMW 1-Series (F20)': ['b38b15',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30o0',
                        'n13b16',
                        'n20b20b',
                        'n55b30',
                        'n47d20'],
 'BMW 1-Series (F21)': ['n13b16', 'n47d20', 'n55b30'],
 'BMW 2-Series (F22)': ['b38b15',
                        'b48b20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30o0',
                        'n20b20u0',
                        'n47d20o1',
                        'n55b30o0'],
 'BMW 2-Series (F23)': ['b38b15',
                        'b48b20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30',
                        'n20b20u0',
                        'n20b20o0',
                        'n55b30o0'],
 'BMW 2-Series Active Tourer (F45)': ['b38b15',
                                      'b38a15m0',
                                      'n20b20',
                                      'n47d20u1'],
 'BMW 3-Series (E21)': ['m10-m98',
                        'm10-m41',
                        'm10-m118',
                        'm10b18',
                        'm10-m43',
                        'm20b20',
                        'm10-m64',
                        'm20b23'],
 'BMW 3-Series (E30)': ['m40b16',
                        'm40b18',
                        'm20b20',
                        'm20b25',
                        'm21d24',
                        'm10b18',
                        'm42b18',
                        'm20b23',
                        'm20b27'],
 'BMW 3-Series (E36)': ['m43b16',
                        'm41d17',
                        'm43b18',
                        'm52b20',
                        'm52b25',
                        'm51d25',
                        'm52b28',
                        'm50b20',
                        'm50b25',
                        'm40b16',
                        'm40b18'],
 'BMW 3-Series (E46)': ['m54b25',
                        'm54b30',
                        'n46b20',
                        'n42b20',
                        'm54b22',
                        'm43b19',
                        'm52b25tu',
                        'm52b28tu',
                        'm47d20tu',
                        'm57d30tu',
                        'n46b18',
                        'm47d20',
                        'm57d30',
                        'm43b19tu',
                        'm52b20tu'],
 'BMW 3-Series (E90)': ['n46b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n52b25a',
                        'n55b30',
                        'n52b25',
                        'n54b30',
                        'n53b30',
                        'm57d30tu2',
                        'n52b30'],
 'BMW 3-Series (F30)': ['b38b15',
                        'b48b20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30',
                        'n20b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n13b16',
                        'n55b30'],
 'BMW 3-Series Gran Turismo (F34)': ['n20b20', 'n47d20', 'b58b30m0', 'n55b30'],
 'BMW 4-Series (F32)': ['b48b20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30',
                        'n20b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n55b30'],
 'BMW 4-Series (F33)': ['b48b20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30',
                        'n20b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n55b30'],
 'BMW 4-Series (F36)': ['b48b20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'b58b30',
                        'n20b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n55b30'],
 'BMW 5-Series (E12)': ['m10b18',
                        'm10b20',
                        'm20b20ve',
                        'm30b25',
                        'm30b28',
                        'm30b28le',
                        'm30b35le'],
 'BMW 5-Series (E28)': ['m10b18',
                        'm20b20le',
                        'm20b20kat',
                        'm30b25',
                        'm21d24',
                        'm20b27',
                        'm30b28le',
                        'm30b35m'],
 'BMW 5-Series (E34)': ['m43b18',
                        'm50b20tu',
                        'm50b25tu',
                        'm51d25',
                        'm60b30',
                        'm60b40',
                        'm40b18',
                        'm50b20',
                        'm50b25',
                        'm20b20',
                        'm20b25',
                        'm21d24',
                        'm30b30',
                        'm30b35'],
 'BMW 5-Series (E39)': ['m47d20',
                        'm54b22',
                        'm54b25',
                        'm57d25',
                        'm54b30',
                        'm57d30',
                        'm62b44tu',
                        'm62b35tu',
                        'm52b20',
                        'm52b25',
                        'm51d25tu',
                        'm52b28',
                        'm62b44',
                        'm51d25',
                        'm62b35'],
 'BMW 5-Series (E60)': ['n43b20ol',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n53b25ul',
                        'n52b25ol',
                        'n53b30ul',
                        'n53b30ol',
                        'n54b30',
                        'm57d30tu2',
                        'm57d30tu2top',
                        'n62b40',
                        'n62b48',
                        'm47tu2d20',
                        'm54b22',
                        'n52b25ul',
                        'm54b25',
                        'm57d25tu',
                        'm54b30',
                        'n52b30',
                        'm57d30tu',
                        'm57d30tutop',
                        'n62b44',
                        'm47d20tu',
                        'm47d20tu2',
                        'n62b48tu'],
 'BMW 5-Series (E61)': ['n43b20ol',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n53b25ul',
                        'n53b30ul',
                        'n53b30ol',
                        'm57d30tu2',
                        'm57d30tu2top',
                        'n62b48',
                        'm47tu2d20',
                        'n52b25ul',
                        'n54b25',
                        'n54b25ol',
                        'm57d25tu',
                        'm54b30',
                        'n52b30',
                        'm57d30tu',
                        'm57d30tutop',
                        'n62b44'],
 'BMW 5-Series (F10)': ['n20b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'b47d20',
                        'n47d20d',
                        'n55b30',
                        'n57d30',
                        'n57d30s1',
                        'n63b44',
                        'n52b25',
                        'n53b30',
                        'n57d30top'],
 'BMW 5-Series (F11)': ['n20b20',
                        'n47d20',
                        'n53b30',
                        'n55b30',
                        'n57d30',
                        'b47d20',
                        'n57d30s1',
                        'n63b44'],
 'BMW 5-Series (G30)': ['b48b20', 'b47d20', 'b58b30', 'b57d30', 'n63b44'],
 'BMW 5-Series Gran Turismo (F07)': ['n55b30', 'n57d30', 'n63b44'],
 'BMW 6-Series (E63)': ['n53b30', 'n62b48', 'n52b30', 'n62b44'],
 'BMW 6-Series (E64)': ['n53b30', 'n62b48', 'n52b30', 'n62b44'],
 'BMW 6-Series (F06)': ['n55b30', 'n57d30', 'n63b44tu'],
 'BMW 6-Series (F12)': ['n55b30', 'n63b44', 'n57d30', 'n55hp'],
 'BMW 6-Series (F13)': ['n55b30', 'n57d30', 'n63b44'],
 'BMW 6-Series Gran Turismo (G32)': ['b48b20', 'b47d20', 'b58b30', 'b57d30'],
 'BMW 7-Series (E23)': ['m30b28le',
                        'm30b33',
                        'm30b35m',
                        'm30b35mae',
                        'm30b28',
                        'm30b30',
                        'm30b33le',
                        'm30b32lae'],
 'BMW 7-Series (E32)': ['m30b30', 'm60b30', 'm30b35le', 'm60b40', 'm70b50'],
 'BMW 7-Series (E38)': ['m51d25',
                        'm52b28tu',
                        'm57d30',
                        'm62tub35',
                        'm62tub44',
                        'm73tub54',
                        'm60b30',
                        'm60b40',
                        'm73b54'],
 'BMW 7-Series (E65)': ['n52b30',
                        'n62b40',
                        'n62b48',
                        'n73b60',
                        'm54b30',
                        'n62b36',
                        'n62b44',
                        'm57d30tu2',
                        'm67d44'],
 'BMW 7-Series (F01)': ['n52b30',
                        'n55b30',
                        'n57d30',
                        'n57d30top',
                        'n63b44tu',
                        'n74b60',
                        'n63b44'],
 'BMW 7-Series (G11, G12)': ['b48b20',
                             'b47d20',
                             'b58b30m0',
                             'n57d30',
                             'b57d30',
                             'b57b30top',
                             'n63b44tu',
                             'n74b66'],
 'BMW 8-Series (E31)': ['m60b40', 'm62b44', 'm70b50', 'm73b54', 's70b56'],
 'BMW 8-Series (G15)': ['b57d30', 'n63b44tu3'],
 'BMW M2 (F87)': ['n55b30t0', 's55b30t0'],
 'BMW M3 (E30)': ['s14b23'],
 'BMW M3 (E36)': ['s50b30', 's50b32'],
 'BMW M3 (E46)': ['s54b32', 's54b32hp'],
 'BMW M3 (E90)': ['s65b40'],
 'BMW M3 (E92)': ['s65b40'],
 'BMW M3 (E93)': ['s65b40'],
 'BMW M3 (F80)': ['s55b30'],
 'BMW M4 (F82)': ['s55b30'],
 'BMW M4 (F83)': ['s55b30'],
 'BMW M5 (E28)': ['m883'],
 'BMW M5 (E34)': ['s38b38', 's38b36'],
 'BMW M5 (E39)': ['s62b50'],
 'BMW M5 (E60)': ['s85b50'],
 'BMW M5 (E61)': ['s85b50'],
 'BMW M5 (F10)': ['s63b44t0'],
 'BMW M5 (F90)': ['s63b44tx'],
 'BMW M6 (E64)': ['s85b50'],
 'BMW M6 (F06)': ['s63b44t0'],
 'BMW M6 (F12)': ['s63b44t0'],
 'BMW M6 (F13)': ['s63b44t0'],
 'BMW X1 (E84)': ['n46b20', 'n20b20', 'n47d20', 'n52b30'],
 'BMW X1 (F48)': ['b38a15m0', 'b48a20m0', 'b48b20', 'b47d20'],
 'BMW X2 (F39)': ['b38a15m1', 'b48a20m1', 'b47c20o1'],
 'BMW X3 (E83)': ['n46b20',
                  'n47d20',
                  'n52b25',
                  'n52b30',
                  'm57d30tu',
                  'm57d30tu2top',
                  'm47tud20',
                  'm54b25',
                  'm54b30',
                  'm57tud30'],
 'BMW X3 (F25)': ['n20b20u0',
                  'n20b20o0',
                  'b47d20',
                  'n55b30m0',
                  'n57d30ol',
                  'n57d30top',
                  'n47d20',
                  'n52b30'],
 'BMW X3 (G01)': ['b48b20', 'b47d20', 'b58b30', 'b57d30'],
 'BMW X4 (F26)': ['n20b20', 'b47d20', 'n55b30', 'n57d30', 'n57d30top'],
 'BMW X4 (G02)': ['b48a20',
                  'b48b20',
                  'b47d20',
                  'n55b30t0',
                  'b57d30m0',
                  'b57d30c'],
 'BMW X5 (E53)': ['m54b30',
                  'm57d30tu',
                  'n62b44',
                  'n62b48',
                  'm62b44tu',
                  'm57d30',
                  'm62b46'],
 'BMW X5 (E70)': ['n55b30',
                  'm57tu2d30',
                  'n57s',
                  'n63b44',
                  's63b44o0',
                  'n52b30',
                  'm57d30tu2',
                  'n62b48',
                  'n57d30ol',
                  'n57d30top',
                  'n57d30s1',
                  's63b44'],
 'BMW X5 (F15)': ['n20b20',
                  'n55b30',
                  'n57d30',
                  'n57d30ol',
                  'n57d30top',
                  'n57d30s1',
                  'n63b44',
                  's63b44'],
 'BMW X5 (G05)': ['b58b30m0', 'b57d30', 'b57d30c', 'n63b44'],
 'BMW X5M E70': [],
 'BMW X6 (E71)': ['n55b30',
                  'n57d30ol',
                  'n57d30top',
                  'n57s',
                  'n63b44',
                  's63b44',
                  'm57d30tu2'],
 'BMW X6 (F16)': ['n55b30',
                  'n57d30l',
                  'n57d30top',
                  'n57d30s1',
                  'n63b44',
                  's63b44'],
 'BMW Z4 (E85)': ['n46b20', 'n52b25', 'n52b30', 's54b32', 'm54b25', 'm54b30'],
 'BMW Z4 (E89)': ['n20b20', 'n54b30', 'n52b25', 'n52b30'],
 'BMW i3': ['w20k06u0'],
 'BMW i3 (I01)': ['w20k06u0'],
 'BMW i8 (I12)': ['b38k15t0'],
 'BMW i8 (l15)': ['b38k15t0']}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое

Answer (score 1):

Учитись правельно парсить и не придется изобретать велосипед :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

src = requests.get('https://bmwband.ru/engines')
soup = BeautifulSoup(src.content, "lxml")
footer = soup.findAll('div', class_='engines-list-page__section_generation col-md-3')

d = {}
for foot in footer:
    ser = foot.b.text
    dv = [x.text for x in foot.findAll('a')]
    d[ser] = dv
print(d)

{'BMW 1-Series (F20)': ['b38b15', 'b47d20', 'b58b30o0', 'n13b16', 'n20b20b', 'n55b30', 'n47d20'], 'BMW 1-Series (F21)': ['n13b16', 'n47d20', 'n55b30'], .... 'BMW Z4 (E85)': ['n46b20', 'n52b25', 'n52b30', 's54b32', 'm54b25', 'm54b30'], 'BMW X5M E70': []}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз учусь. Это мой первый проект на Питоне, поэтому так...